# Get From, To, Subject and Date from Outlook Mail Item

Tags: vba, outlook

I need help to add Date, From, To and Suject to construct a pdf filename.

```
'Construct a safe file name from the message subject
Dim msgFileName As String
msgFileName = MySelectedItem.Subject

Set oRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
oRegEx.Global = True
oRegEx.Pattern = "[\/:*?""<>|]"
msgFileName = Trim(oRegEx.Replace(msgFileName, ""))
```

I have this code, but it only saves Subject in filename. I try to construct like this, but not works:
    `msgFileName = MySelectedItem.Subject.From.To`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough for the concatenation of the four parts:

```
msgFileName = mySelectedItem.SentOn & mySelectedItem.Subject & mySelectedItem.SentOnBehalfOfName & mySelectedItem.To
```

To split the line into multiple lines, making the code a bit more readable, splitting with `-`:

```
msgFileName = mySelectedItem.SentOn & "-" & _
                mySelectedItem.Subject & "-" & _
                mySelectedItem.SentOnBehalfOfName & "-" & _
                mySelectedItem.To
```

Comment: Thank you. But it has a error:Object does not support this property or method.

Comment: @PauloFerreira - how did you declare the `mySelectedItem` in this line of your code - `msgFileName = MySelectedItem.Subject`?

Comment: @PauloFerreira - I have thought that you have checked the mail properties, and the only problem was the concatenation. You are getting that error, because the properties were not correct. I have edited the answer, to refer to the correct ones.

Comment: 'Retrieve the selected item
    Set mySelectedItem = MyOlSelection.Item(1)

Comment: @PauloFerreira - try the updated code, it should work.

Comment: Amazing! It works! Thank you. One more question: How can I separate those values with (-) character?

Comment: @PauloFerreira - You are welcome. I have edited the second code, adding the `-`.

Comment: @PauloFerreira - true, there were two `&`, next to each other.